# MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012) - Audio sounds strange and have low quality

Tags: macos, audio, macbook-pro

The Audio hasn't sound right in my Macbook since the day I installed the
[movavi](http://www.movavi.com/mac-screen-capture/) screen-capture program.

I have:

- Uninstalled the program.
- [Uninstalled movavi sound grabber](http://img.movavi.com/online-help/screencapturemac/2/uninstalling_movavi_sound_grabber.htm?mw=MzUy&st=MA==&sct=MA==&ms=EgEB), that was still left in the system after first uninstall
- Restarted the MacBook.
- Reset the firmware.

The volume is still low and it feels a bit like listening through a tin foil paper.

It's the same if I use headphones.

Any tips on what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening up /Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup and changing the settings for the Built-in Output. I once had similar audio issues and changing these settings seemed to help. See [this Apple Support link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5323719?start=15&tstart=0) for others who have had similar issues.

Hope this helps!